# Failed to load ApplicationContext (with annotation)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, spring-security

This is my class for test.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
public class UserServiceImplIT {

    @Autowired
    private SampleService sampleService; 

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
        System.out.println("-----> SETUP <-----");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSampleService() {
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

exception (many exceptions, main :
 `Failed to load ApplicationContext`,
 `Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping'`.
`Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception;`,
`A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling`
)

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
>       at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:228)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:249)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' defined in class org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping]: Factory method 'defaultServletHandlerMapping' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A ServletContext is required to configure default servlet handling
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)

AppConfig - basic configuration file.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.moneymanager.web")
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
@Import({SecurityConfig.class,})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public SampleService getSampleService() {
        return new SampleServiceImpl();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/pages/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);

        return resolver;
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"ru.moneymanager.web"});
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

SecurityConfig

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.moneymanager.web")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    AuthenticationService authenticationService;
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        CharacterEncodingFilter filter = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        filter.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        filter.setForceEncoding(true);
        // отключена защита csrf на время тестов
        http.csrf().disable().addFilterBefore(filter,CsrfFilter.class);
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/account/**").hasRole("USER")
            .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .and().formLogin();
    }
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(authenticationService);
    }   
}
```

other configuration files [config](https://github.com/Money-control/maoneymanagerrep/tree/CreateTestsForServices/src/main/java/ru/moneymanager/web/config)
this project in git  [project](https://github.com/Money-control/maoneymanagerrep/tree/CreateTestsForServices/src)
tell me, what's wrong? Why the error?

Comment: You're using JUnit to test your MVC controllers as if they were deployed inside a real servlet container? If so, JUnit is not a servlet container; you may find this link useful: http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-mvc-test-tutorial/

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your test requires a ServletContext: add `@WebIntegrationTest`

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class, loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@WebIntegrationTest
public class UserServiceImplIT
```

...or look here for other options: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html

**UPDATE**
In Spring Boot 1.4.x and above `@WebIntegrationTest` is no longer preferred. `@SpringBootTest` or `@WebMvcTest`

Answer (score 12):

Was able to fix the same issue with the annotation below. So in this case only the target class (Abc.class) is used by Spring, not the whole app context.

```
@SpringBootTest(properties = "spring.main.lazy-initialization=true",
classes = {Abc.class})
```

Answer (score 11):

In my case, I had to do the following while running with Junit5

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = {abc.class})
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class
```

Here abc.class was the class that was being tested

Answer (score 4):

You can add to your `application.yml` in tests resources `lazy-initialization`:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: service
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    lazy-initialization: true
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who only entering Unit testing and had encountered this problem - before running a test please make sure that application can be started correctly...
I personally made a change in my RouteBuilder, hasn't checked that it's working and started tests, please don't do that.

Comment: This looks more like a comment instead of an answer.