# How to integration test repository in Spring boot

Tags: java, mysql, spring, integration-testing

I am new to Spring Boot, made my first Entity. How can I test the repository?
I am using a local MySQL Database. So first step would be mocking the Database?

```
    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @DataJpaTest
    public class ClusterTest {

        @Autowired
        private TestEntityManager testEntityManager;

        @Autowired
        private ClusterRepository clusterRepository;

        @Test
        public void testExample() throws Exception{
            this.testEntityManager.persist(new Cluster("Project", "System"));
Cluster cluster = this.clusterRepository.findOne(1);
            assertThat(testcluster.getProject()).isEqualTo("System");
        }

    }
```

This is my cluster entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Cluster")
public class Cluster {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    private String project;

    public Cluster(){

    }

    public Cluster(String project) {
        this.project = project;

    }
```

And my repository just extends JpaRepository.

The error i'm getting is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext. And a bit down : Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoconfigureTestDatabase.

This is my application.properties file from src/main/resources/application.properties:

```
security.basic.enabled=false
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

I copied this file to my src/test/resources/application.properties

And the error

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to replace DataSource with an embedded database for tests. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath or tune the replace attribute of @AutoconfigureTestDatabase.
```

Comment: You are getting error because you haven't specified the spring configuration file in the test class.

Comment: Do you want the complete example or just solution for your error ?

Comment: @VivekSingh If possible the example. I'm very new to this all. So I can know what I did wrong, and learn from it

Comment: See this link http://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Comment: @VivekSingh I did the exact same thing and got the error. My code that I posted is almost the same

Comment: can you post the complete error/exception log and see these links https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36519220/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-with-annotation  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21561432/failed-to-load-applicationcontext-during-spring-unit-test

Comment: @VivekSingh Added the error

Comment: Refer to the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41316559/16916419)

Answer (score 5):

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE)
public class ClusterTests {

@Autowired
    private TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    private ClusterRepository clusterRepository;
}
```

This should work in getting rid of the in memory database generation. The best way would be to use an in memory database to which you persist your entity, but another good method would be to use your database directly. By using @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = NONE) you tell spring to not replace the datasource.

Hope it helps